# Why MongooseJS is reversing the order of properties?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've noticed that if we insert an object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, in database it'll be stored as {c: 3, b:2, a: 1}. Why is MongooseJS doing this?

Is it for Performance Gain (or) some other logic?

Could anyone please explain this to me in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering of properties in objects is complex, as this answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/893780

Even though it's not specified in the standard, normal property keys are stored in insertion order.

Internally, Mongoose uses a faster code path when cloning objects, that reverses the property order. It basically does this:

```
let oldObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let newObject = {};

let keys = Object.keys(oldObject);
let i    = keys.length;

while (i--) {
  let k   = keys[i];
  let val = oldObject[k];
  newObject[k] = val;
}
```

Because normal keys are stored in insertion order, `newObject` will be the reverse of `oldObject`:

```
{ c: 3, b: 2, a: 1 }
```

However, because this can cause issues in queries, Mongoose added an option [`retainKeyOrder`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder) to prevent this reversal.

However, according to the same answer that I linked to above, you still can't rely on any order being imposed when using `Object.keys()` or `for..in`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as properties order in object. If the order is important for you use an array.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in original insertion order. For each distinct property [...]

However this seems to be implementation (browser) dependant.
In objects you can't rely on order of the properties as even various iteration methods may give various results.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that properties order should not be considered in object. But If you're using a for..in loop, properties with numerical key[0-9] are sorted and handled before the alphanumeric keys [a-zA-Z0-9_.........]

Comment: If we're going to calculate the checksum of that object before and after insertion will produce different results

Comment: And also my question is about the logic behind the properties order reversal. which MongooseJS have implemented.

Comment: @ARAVINDKUMAR.S objects don't have an order. Any observed reversal of properties, or a particular order shown when iterating the object, should be considered to be purely coincidental and random, and cannot be relied upon.

Comment: For preserving the order, we need to set retainKeyOrder property to true in the schema options.

Comment: @robertklep, why do they've provided for retainKeyOrder property.